# Multiplying all variables in certain columns in dataset

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

For example my dataframe looks like this:

| Tr | leu | type of smth |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 150 | 20 | 0 |
| 200 | 10 | 1 |
| 350 | 26 | 1 |
| 170 | 16 | 0 |

I need to choose only Tr and Leu columns and to multiply them on 100. The problem is that I have 12 such columns like Tr or Leu and want to automate the process. I feel there are simple ways to do it but have not got them yet.

Finally I get the results I needed with the following code in R:

```
data$cd3 <- 100*data$cd3
data$cd4 <- 100*data$cd4
data$cd5 <- 100*data$cd5 
data$cd6 <- 100*data$cd6
data$cd7 <- 100*data$cd7
data$cd8 <- 100*data$cd8
data$cd9 <- 100*data$cd9
data$cd10 <- 100*data$cd10
data$cd11 <- 100*data$cd11
```

I also tried:

```
data<-data %>%
  mutate(cd3 <- 100*cd3
         cd4 <- 100*cd4,
         cd5 <- 100*cd5 
         cd6 <- 100*cd6
         cd7 <- 100*cd7
         cd8 <- 100*cd8
         cd9 <- 100*cd9
         cd10 <- 100*cd10
         cd11 <- 100*cd11)
```

but my dataframe didn't change.

Also tried function

```
data%>%
select (starts_with (cd) %>%
...
```

but didn't get what to do the next.

Comment: sorry, the table was clearly visible in the preview

Comment: With *dplyr* try `df %>% mutate(across(-3, ~ .x * 100))`. Here, 3 is the index of the column to leave out. Additionally take a look at `?dplyr::select` to see some other select options when using `across`.

Answer (score 1):

In base R, have a look at `?grepl` to do something like:

```r
df[grepl("^Tr|^leu", colnames(df))] = df[grepl("^Tr|^leu", colnames(df))] * 100L
```

gives

```r
> df
     Tr  leu   Tr2 type.of.smth
1 15000 2000 10000            0
2 20000 1000 20000            1
3 35000 1600 30000            1
4 17000 2600 40000            0
```

and `{dplyr}`

```r
library(dplyr)
df =  
  df |> mutate(across(matches("^Tr|^leu"), ~ .x * 100L))
```

---

Toy data:

```r
df = data.frame(Tr = c(150, 200, 350, 170), leu = c(20, 10, 16, 26), 
                Tr2 = c(1:4) * 100, `type of smth` = c(0, 1, 1, 0))
```

Answer (score -1):

As an example, here is how you can mutiply columns 2 and 4 of the iris dataset by 100:

```
d = iris
mycols = c(2,4)
d[,mycols] = 100*d[,mycols]
```

Comment: It also works using names instead of index values: mycols = c("Sepal.Width", "Petal.Width")

Comment: You may wanna include your comment in the answer provided. Comments won't get as much attention. Cheers.